# How can I rename file uploaded to s3 using javascript api?

Tags: filepicker.io

- 'pickAndStore' method allows me to specify full path to the file, but I don't know it's extension at this point (file path has to be defined before file is uploaded, so it's not possible to provide a path with correct extension).
- if I use 'pick' and then 'store' I have 2 files (because both methods uploads file to the s3). I can delete 'old' file, but it's not optimal and can be pain (take ages) with really big files.

Is there any better solution? Ideally to rename existing file.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no workaround for renaming file.

However, in our Javascript API v2 we are planing to add new callback function. onStart callback will be fired after user pick file but before file uploading. There could be option like renaming file based on original filename.

We will keep you updated.